# printf member of struct

Tags: c, struct, printf

I am having trouble using printf to print a single member of a struct. 
I have a struct which consists of char arrays. When trying to print a single member like this:

```
printf("%s", header.oscar_fname);
```

It prints the entire struct. I cannot figure out where I am going wrong here.

Comment: This looks like an assignment from cs344... @i486 is probably correct, if you read the struct like instructed in class, you won't have a null terminator at the end of oscar_fname which will cause printf to print the entire struct.

Comment: @Jacobm001: Unless properly asked, with a different format.

Answer (score 3):

You have to show the struct definition and how you assign values. But I am 90% sure that you don't have terminating zero byte for struct member and for that reason `printf` prints all following members. Use `strcpy` to set member value or set last byte/char to 0: `header.oscar_fname[sizeof header.oscar_fname - 1] = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%.*s", (int)sizeof header.oscar_fname, header.oscar_fname);
```

That prints the contents of the specified array, up to a 0-terminator if present.

[man `printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) gives all the options.